# Embed a website/page into Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

Yes that sounds backwards. I want to create an area or frame in my Silverlight app to host another page from my site. I've seen it done before but I can't seem to find any examples.

This way I can control the entire page layout using SL but still use existing aspx pages.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done and its quite easy to do. I plan on blogging about my HtmlBrowser control and posting the source. The basics are to make sure the Silverlight control is hosted with the isWindowless parameter enabled and then you can at runtime through the HtmlPage class create an IFRAME element and set the src attribute to the HTML page location. The fun part is getting the sizing right, but its not too difficult.

Follow my blog http://craign.net/ over the next couple of days as I'll post my control.

Comment: It would help the community if you post more details here as well as your blog, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Will frame break out code break out or not when using this technique.